# SignalR - Client method not called when user is unauthorised

Tags: asp.net-mvc, client, authorization, signalr

Simply I have comments section, and when I post some comment to the database, signalr is calling a method on all clients.

```
var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationsHub>();
hub.Clients.All.updateBlogComments(Mapper.Map<BlogCommentViewModel>(comment));
```

The problem is that when a user, who is just a visitor of the page and is not logged into the system, doesn't get called the client method updateBlogComments.

If there are 2 logged users visiting the same page, the method is called on both users, and there is no problem.But when a logged user posts a comment, the unauthorized user won't get the newly uploaded comment as it should.

How can I fix that.I want authorized and non-authorized users to see live comments uploading.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure unauthorized users connect properly to the hub? Maybe the code path that connects to the hub is not executed for unauthorized users or your hub endpoint requires authorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED.

I knowingly created a separate hub for this action which doesn't require authorization, but I forgot to change the name of the hubcontext, which I was taking, so instead of CommentsHub, I was still calling NotificationsHub.

Thanks to @Stilgar, for reminding me where the problem could be.